# Implications of SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the meaning and implications of the following error messages
    *** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
    *** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
    *** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!

which appears when I boot up rails s

```
C:\PRJ4RAILS\rnd>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
 Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Answer (score 10):

It means that your system (Windows, I presume?) does not respond to the `USR2`, `USR1`, or `HUP` signals, so you can't use them to restart Puma or reopen the log files. (If you're interested, the syntax would look like `kill -SIGUSR1 1234`, where `1234` is the Puma process ID.)

If you don't need either of those capabilities, then I think you can ignore those warnings.

If you do need those capabilities, you'll need to move to a platform that supports those signals, such as Linux or OS X.

Comment: Is there some patch for windows or something else...?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I don't develop on Windows any more.